# Different cursor pointers for different html tags

Tags: html, css

I am trying to render

```
if(path == "not supported") {                     
    return $('<p>',{"class" : "color-black font13_20"}).text(path);
}
else {
 return $('<a>',{"class" : "wrap-text-span getWidthP color-ublue font13_20", "href": path, "target":"_blank"}).text(path);
}
```

This gives me the desired results where if path is `not supported` I get a `<p>` in black colour with no hyperlink while if the path does not have `not supported` I get a hyperlink in blue colour. But in the both the cases I get cursor of type pointer. I wanted to have default cursor when it goes in if block and pointer cursor if it goes in else.

Comment: perhaps, add a unique identifier to your not-supported message and then use the css `cursor:default;`?

Comment: How does the rendered html actually look like when _not supported_?

Comment: You don't have `.font13_20 {cursor:...` somewhere in your CSS by mistake, do you?

Comment: @love2code did one of the answers answer your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following rules to your CSS

```
p.color-black {
    cursor: not-allowed;
}

a.color-ublue {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason your p tag inherits a cursor style from a parent element. so you need to set it to back to the default behaviour.

```
p {
    cursor:auto;
}
```

or with a class applied in the p tag:

```
.reset-cursor {
    cursor:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this if it works for you...

```
if(path == "not supported") {                     
return $('<p>',{"class" : "color-black font13_20",/*use inline css style here for cursor -> style="cursor:auto;"*/}).text(path);
}
else {
 return $('<a>',{"class" : "wrap-text-span getWidthP color-ublue font13_20", "href": path, "target":"_blank"}).text(path);
}
```

I dont know the coding convention of language you use .. So do it yourself... I have add where and what to add...... This may solve your problem...